# What does Ubuntu Core consist of?

Tags: ubuntu-core

Exactly what does [**Ubuntu Core**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core) consist of?

I know of a similar project called [Ubuntu Mini Remix](http://www.ubuntu-mini-remix.org/), which, while not an official Ubuntu project, is [known to contain](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mini-remix/+faq/33):

- [ubuntu-minimal](http://tinyurl.com/2cpw6o) metapackage
- [ubuntu-standard](http://tinyurl.com/2cpw6o)
- casper
- lupin-casper

What does Ubuntu Core contain?

What are the differences between the purposes of these two projects?

I would like to make sure of this before I choose a starting point to build my own Ubuntu derivative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [release directory](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/12.04/release/) for the ".manifest" files which list every package (eg. [ubuntu-core-12.04.4-core-amd64.manifest](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/12.04/release/ubuntu-core-12.04.4-core-amd64.manifest)). *Ubuntu Core* is just a minimal install of Ubuntu, you could make something very similar yourself by running:

```
mkdir chroot
debootstrap --arch=amd64 trusty chroot http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

*Ubuntu Core* is just a minimal rootfs of around 60MB size whereas *Ubuntu Mini Remix* is a 200MB iso live image.

Comment: Why isn't  `linux` kernel listed in the **manifest**? What files are supposed to be listed there?

Comment: All of the packages that are installed in the root filesystem. The linux kernel probably isn't there because it isn't installed in the root filesystem - either users are expected to boot it separately from whatever bootloader they are using, or just install or build their own kernel.

Comment: Keep in mind that the **compressed** [rootfs of "Ubuntu Core"](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/) has almost doubled in size (amd64) [**63M**](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/14.04/release/) since release 14.04, before 14.04 core rootfs was [**38M**](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/releases/13.10/release/).

Comment: And "Ubuntu Core" 15.04 (snappy) amd64 doubled again to **132M** after decompression, and 47M before decompression.