# What is Ubuntu Core?

Tags: ubuntu-core

What exactly is Ubuntu Core, and how does it relate to Ubuntu itself (i.e. the main desktop and server distribution)?

I've read [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/483036/11317) to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482998/what-does-ubuntu-core-consist-of), which says it's just a minimal install of Ubuntu, but it says nothing about the "snappy" transactional updates that Mark Shuttleworth mentioned in [his blog post](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1434).

Comment: Perhaps [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/snappy) explains it a bit better?

Comment: If you are seeking other information please be more specific on what you're asking for. Your question is otherwise vague in its current state.

Comment: Also see: http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2014/12/its-a-snap.html

Comment: @Thomas W. Sorry I was not clear. I was trying to figure out if there was a difference between the newly announced Ubuntu Core and the one that's been around for a while. The first link you posted claims it's "a new rendition of Ubuntu for the cloud with transactional updates", so since the answer to the "duplicate" of my question states that it's "just a minimal install of Ubuntu" and dates from months ago, I though these might be two different things.

Comment: @AibaraIduas Given that you've marked my answer as accepted, I assume it answered your question?  (Although the duplicate is still marked and valid)

Comment: @Thomas W. It explained the Snappy bit well, thanks. I'm just putting the answers together in my head now I suppose: Ubuntu Core is now a minimal install with this new way of updating. (Correct me if I'm wrong though!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the brief explanation of Snappy on the main Ubuntu site: ([source](http://www.ubuntu.com/snappy))

> Ubuntu Core is a new rendition of Ubuntu for the cloud with transactional updates. Ubuntu Core is a minimal server image with the same libraries as today’s Ubuntu, but applications are provided through a simpler mechanism. The snappy approach is faster, more reliable, and lets us provide stronger security guarantees for apps and users — that’s why we call them “snappy” applications.
>
> Snappy apps and Ubuntu Core itself can be upgraded atomically and rolled back if needed — a bulletproof approach to systems management that is perfect for container deployments. It’s called “transactional” or “image-based” systems management, and we’re delighted to make it available on every Ubuntu certified cloud.

Comment: What exactly is the 'snappy approach'...

Comment: @Wilf perhaps you'd like to go view the extremely in depth and much too big to fit on ask ubuntu page which I link to with the source link?  That's the true source of information on this.

Comment: Yeah, sorry just had a quick look due to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/605066/what-is-snappy-ubuntu-core?lq=1). I couldn't find much other than their some special thing involving tarballs (though there is now a great answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/605087/178596)) - probably ought to try it :D

Comment: The link `http://www.ubuntu.com/snappy` in the answer redirects to `https://ubuntu.com/desktop/developers`.  https://web.archive.org/ only has copies of the redirection from the server since 2014.12.28.  If you find the page elsewhere, it would be nice to read.