# Does Xubuntu 16.04 have the ubuntu snap installed?

Tags: xubuntu, 16.04, snap

I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 beta 2 to 16.04 LTS recently and read [How To Install And Remove Snap Packages In Ubuntu 16.04](http://itsfoss.com/use-snap-packages-ubuntu-16-04/).

But when I run `snap list` I am getting the following output:

```
error: no snaps found
```

Does Xubuntu also have snap packaging or is this only for Ubuntu?

Output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Ubuntu Core?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/558627/what-is-ubuntu-core)

Comment: Ubuntu Core is an image in itself. Xubuntu != Ubuntu Core.

Comment: @muru acoording to the above web site ubuntu-core was installed by default as a snap. So shouldn't it be the same for me??

Comment: You're not using Ubuntu Core. You're using a desktop image. Try the images from https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/

Comment: @muru : Mohit Rajan meant the snap packaging support in Ubuntu 16.04  (some people just call it Ubuntu core) ... please read my answer ... this question is not a duplicate. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox I disagree. OP doesn't know what Ubuntu Core is. That's where the problem lies.

Comment: @cl-netbox If OP wants that, then they can edit the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Canonical unveils 6th LTS release of Ubuntu with 16.04 - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS adds new “snap” application package format, enabling further convergence across IOT, mobile and desktop](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/20/canonical-unveils-6th-lts-release-of-ubuntu-with-16-04/).

You just get this output because you currently have no snap packages installed ... execute :

```
snap find
```

The output shows the currently available packages :

```
Name                   Version                  Summary  
canonical-dragon       0.7.1                    The gadget snap for the dragonboard  
canonical-i386         3.1                      The gadget snap for generic i386 systems  
canonical-pc           3.1                      AMD64 generic package  
canonical-pc-linux     4.4.0-18+20160419.13-26  The ubuntu-core kernel snap  
canonical-pi2          3.2                      Raspberry Pi 2 support package  
go-example-webserver   16.04-4                  Minimal Golang webserver for snappy  
hello-world            6.0                      Hello world example  
http                   4.6692016                HTTPie in a snap  
links                  2.12-1                   Web browser running in text mode  
moon-buggy             1.0.51.9                 Drive a car across the moon  
nmap                   7.12SVN-0.4              Nmap ("Network Mapper") is a free and open source utility for network discovery and security auditing  
notes-dpm              0.0.8+snap1              Note-taking application, write down your thoughts  
shout                  0.53.0                   A self hosted web IRC client  
sshtron                1.0                      multiplayer Tron via ssh  
tor-middle-relay       0.2.7.6-6                Essential infrastructure node for Tor network  
ubuntu-calculator-app  2.1+snap3                Ubuntu Calculator application for the Unity 7 desktop  
ubuntu-clock-app       3.6+snap3                Ubuntu Clock application for the Unity 7 desktop  
ubuntu-core            16.04+20160419.20-55     The ubuntu-core OS snap  
xkcd-webserver         16.04-5                  Show random XKCD compic via a build-in webserver
```

To install a snap package execute :

```
sudo snap install <package-name>
```

After having installed packages, `snap list` will show you the installed packages.

For more information about all available snap commands execute : `snap --help`.

Example :

```
sudo snap install nmap
```

Result :

```
snap list
Name         Version               Developer
nmap         7.12SVN-0.4           joetalbott
ubuntu-core  16.04+20160419.20-55  canonical
```