# Why are there no new Ubuntu (core) Snappy releases?

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-core

I'm looking at the [image channel guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/channels/) for developers of Ubuntu Snappy Core. The only release available is 15.04. To me this seems odd; on the desktop and server side there has been a 15.10 and a 16.04 release since the 15.04. Does Ubuntu Snappy not follow the release convention? When can one expect a new release?

Comment: Most likely the devs are busy with 16.04 desktop and will get to snappy in due time.

Comment: Indeed, snappy is on the desktop as described in the answer, but you're not insane-- snappy ubuntu core 16 images don't exist yet. They'll be out soon.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have missed it ... Ubuntu snap support comes pre-installed in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. [Canonical unveils 6th LTS release of Ubuntu with 16.04 - Introduces “snaps” for new robust secure app format](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/20/canonical-unveils-6th-lts-release-of-ubuntu-with-16-04/). Check out which applications are available by executing -> `snap find`.

Execute `snap --help` to get a list of currently available commands. When you want to run snappy images the way you used to do it before, you can download the latest versions [here](https://people.canonical.com/~mvo/all-snaps/).
Some more information and an example on how it works : [Snap support in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761813/does-xubuntu-16-04-have-the-ubuntu-snap-installed/761822#761822)

Comment: So what would be the 16.04 equivalent of the Snappy Core ISO? Just a minimal install of the Ubuntu Server ISO?

Comment: @NickWeinberg : When you execute sudo snap install ubuntu-core you will see that the minimal image of ubuntu-core gets downloaded ... if I remember it correctly, it is about 65 MB. but when you download the image from https://people.canonical.com/~mvo/all-snaps/ the file is equivalent to what you downloaded before. :)

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion but I was referring to Ubuntu Snappy Core and not just Snappy

Answer (score 0):

Here is more information:
https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/kvm

With the download link for 64 bit Ubuntu snappy core 16.04:

```
wget http://releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/ubuntu-core-16-amd64.img.xz
```