# Does "ubuntu core" os support ftp?

Tags: ubuntu-core

I am gathering information for my project about "Ubuntu core " OS feature
Please share infomation about FTP in Ubuntu core OS.
Does **Ubuntu Core** support FTP?

Comment: Please, we don't do your homework. Try to do some basic research before asking here.

Comment: Everybody know that Clasic Ubuntu/Ubuntu desktop and other flaovours support FTP. But Ubuntu core doesn't specify anyware that it support FTP. I appreciate you tell me the answer but if you dont know please don't do **MY HOME WORK**

Comment: An operating system does (normally) not support ftp. Applications do. Ubuntu core can run applications. How you want to interact with FTP dictates what software you will use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Ubuntu Core?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558627/what-is-ubuntu-core)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this awnser from a related question: [What is Snappy Ubuntu Core?](https://askubuntu.com/a/605087/886378)
By that you see that there is a package manager called [Snappy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snappy_%28package_manager%29).
By using snappy you can download apps and install them. Checkout the [web store](https://snapcraft.io/store) to search for your ftp software. If there is some software you are unable to find, i would recommend to use [docker](https://snapcraft.io/docker) and run a container that provides you the wanted service. Here are some [containers related to sftp](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=sftp%20server&starCount=0).(always use sftp instead of ftp unless you DONT have to worry about security, [here is why](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/internet/difference-between-ftp-and-sftp/))