# Ubuntu for Docker Containers

Tags: 14.04, docker

Is Ubuntu a suitable distro for using inside a Docker container? If so, how does the Ubuntu installed by

```
docker pull ubuntu
```

differ from Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Official Ubuntu base image available at [Docker Hub Registry](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/) is based on [Ubuntu Core](https://askubuntu.com/q/482998/65926) released by [Canonical](https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/trusty/current/).

[Core's page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Core) on Ubuntu Wiki explicitly states it is suitable for use in Docker (emphasis mine):

> Ubuntu Core is a minimal rootfs for use in the creation of custom images for specific needs. **Ubuntu Core strives to create a suitable minimal environment for use in** Board Support Packages, constrained or integrated environments, as the basis for application demonstration images, or **Linux containers such as** [LXC](https://linuxcontainers.org/) or **[Docker](http://docker.io/)**.

The [manifest file](https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/trusty/current/ubuntu-trusty-core-cloudimg-amd64.manifest) contains the list of pre-installed packages. Of course, you can install any package available in the Ubuntu repos, but you may have a hard time trying to run GUI applications inside a container.